# Kivy: How to switch between interfaces defined in different classes

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm developing an app in Kivy/KivyMD - Python. I defined three different UI in three different classes. Each interface contains a button to switch between them. When the app starts, the first interface is displayed.
Here is the code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.relativelayout import MDRelativeLayout

Builder.load_string(
    """   
<View3>:
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'GO TO VIEW 1'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.7, 'center_y': 0.7}
        #on_release:
    

<View2>:
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'GO TO VIEW 3'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        #on_release:

    
    
<View1>:
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'GO TO VIEW 2'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.3}
        #on_release: 
    
"""
)


    
class View3(MDRelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    

class View2(MDRelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)      
        

class View1(MDRelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.view = View1()

    def build(self):
        return View1()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

How can I switch between them?

Comment: That's exactly the sort of thing that [ScreenManager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html) was designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use KivyMD myself, but you could use `ScreenManager` and `Screen` (check out the [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#)).

Example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string(
    """   
<View3>:
    Button:
        text: 'GO TO VIEW 1'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.7, 'center_y': 0.7}
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'view1'


<View2>:
    Button:
        text: 'GO TO VIEW 3'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'view3'



<View1>:
    Button:
        text: 'GO TO VIEW 2'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.3}
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'view2'
"""
)


class View3(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class View2(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class View1(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class MainApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        self.sm.add_widget(View1(name="view1"))
        self.sm.add_widget(View2(name="view2"))
        self.sm.add_widget(View3(name="view3"))

    def build(self):
        return self.sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

You can change the views with `ScreenManager.current` property, or `root.manager.current` from the kv.

Note that KivyMD has its equivalents for this widgets: [`MDScreenManager`](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.1/components/screenmanager/) and [`MDScreen`](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.1/components/screen/#kivymd.uix.screen.MDScreen), so you can probably use them as well.

Also, note that these Screens already inherit from `RelativeLayout`. If you really need to use another layout, I would suggest to add it in the kv.